# remove clustering onclick bingmaps

Tags: angular, bing-maps, angular-maps

I am Using Bingmaps angular-maps(Xmap) in my project and i am using clustering layer as in below Screenshot.
[image: Clustering layer on Bingmaps]

And on Click of a cluster the parent cluster in getting clustered again into smaller Clusters like below screenshot.

[image]

But what i want to achieve is when a user clicks on particular cluster, I want to avoid the further clustering of my Pushpins, instead i want to show all my pushpins under that cluster.
Please help !!

I am using Angular-maps(xmap) Bingmap.

Stackblitz link for the infusioncode Bing-maps with clustering layer is as below.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bing-map-with-databound-cluster-layer)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the pushpins are too close and the grid size is too big to handle it automatically.

I had similar issue and my first idea was to remove whole clustering layer, but after removing it also the containing puspins were removed

I found a solution by changing the girdsize on a certain zoom level and works like a charm

```
let lastZoomLevel = map.current.getZoom();
const handleChangeZoom = e => {
  if (lastZoomLevel !== map.current.getZoom()) {
    lastZoomLevel = map.current.getZoom();
  
    if (map.getZoom() >= 12) {
      map.layers[0].setOptions({ gridSize: 1 });
    } else {
      map.layers[0].setOptions({ gridSize: 80 });
    }
  }
}

window.Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map.current, 'viewchangeend', handleChangeZoom);
```